# Resample daily pandas DataFrame to the last day in the month given a particular series (not necessarily end of calendar month)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas DataFrame that contains daily stock prices. I want to resample the daily date index to monthly by taking the last date in the month for every month range that I have. For example, if I have a range from 2022-07-01 to 2022-07-22, I want to resample by taking the price of 2022-07-22.

I did this by using the following:

```
df.sort_index().resample('M').apply(lambda i: i.iloc[-1])
```

This worked and returned the last daily price in a given month. However, I am facing the following issue:
If my month ends in say 2022-07-22, my output returns the correct price value for 2022-07-22 but changes the date from 2022-07-22 to 2022-07-31.

Is there a way to resample to the last month given my particular daily series instead of generically using the resample('M') which returns the last month of a generic calendar period?

I hope I was able to clarify what I am trying to do. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: not sure i get your question.. but sounds like a lazy way to do it would be 1, assign a new column for yyyymm (but which takes the form of the last date in your data... you can assign this keeping the same rowcount using groupny.transform, 2, group the values in the series by this yyyymm column, with a similar aggregator as what you're using (last value)

Comment: The lazy way worked like a charm, thanks!